# SLF4J uses Logback even though Logbag is excluded in my pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, log4j, logback

I am using Log4j 2 for logging, and therefore want to bind SLF4J to my logger using the log4j-slf4j-impl.jar. One dependency (tess4j) implements Logback, which also binds SLF4J, causing a conflict and ultimately leads to SLf4J binding to Logback, ignoring my logger. i have tried to exclude logback from tess4j, with no effect however. Is there a way to rout messages from logback to Log4J, or can i check if any other dependency is using logback (Eclipse's dependency hierarchy doesnt show any other use)?

Comment: "I have tried to exclude logback from tess4j, with no effect however."  You should tell us **how** you tried to do this; i.e. show us the POM file excerpts.

Answer (score 1):

There may be another library that uses Logback, you may want to check further your dependency tree in maven by executing `mvn dependency:tree` and analyzing the output.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out i had a second, manually added tess4j.jar in my build path that was used instead of the maven one